# Genius feature doesn't work on iPhone

Tags: iphone, music, itunes-store

I purchase all my music through iTunes, yet I can never get the genius feature to work on my iPhone 4S.

Whenever I press the genius button in the music app it says "This song does not have enough related songs to create a Genius Playlist."

But with 15 GB of music all from the iTunes store, I'm doubting this.

For example, it says this with Skrillex's new EP, but there are at least half a dozen other albums in the same genre that it should easily be able to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refresh your Genius results in iTunes and then re-sync your phone with iTunes. Then you should be able to generate Genius playlists on your phone.

To refresh your Genius results:

1. Open iTunes
2. Sync your phone with iTunes so all your purchased music is in your current iTunes library.
3. Make sure Genius is on. If you select Store from the menu bar and it says "Turn off Genius" you're all set. Otherwise select Store -> Turn on Genius.
4. Now select Store -> Update Genius

iTunes will think for a while and eventually the status area at the top of the main window will say "Delivering your Genius results...".

When it's done delivering your Genius results sync your phone with iTunes. You should have Genius playlist capabilities on your phone now.